# Save filled couchbase lite db as a backup in nativescript and vue?

Tags: nativescript, couchbase, nativescript-vue, couchbase-lite

May I save a couchbase db as a backup on the localfilesystem?

It should work on IOS and Android.

On IOS I have an App: "Files" with data "on my iphone" from Firefox or Recorder App or other Apps always in a directory.
How can I save the backup in a directory in this location?

I found something about push replication with couchbase, but only remote.
Is it possible to make a push replication to the local filesystem to solve this?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you facing only on vue/native-script? and iOS/Android works fine?

Comment: I'm facing on nativescript - javascript and it should work on both, iOS and Android. Vue is not a must have.

Comment: You can use the DatabaseConfiguration to set the directory where the database is saved in iPhone folders like Application Support/Temporary etc, or a shared App Group which are accessible by the Application. But saving as a separate backup, what's the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: Jay, to save some data, I don't want to go online. So I like to store it locally.

Comment: CouchbaseLite saves data locally.

Answer (score 2):

A Couchbase Lite database is a directory.  Copying the directory will back up the database.

The backup, of course, will not stay up-to-date.  Also, be careful using db copies in replication scenarios.  Databases have ids that are assumed to be unique.  Multiple copies (which will have the same id) will encumber the replication process.